# Can xcode have files shared between projects and edited independently?

Tags: xcode, file, project

When building iOS projects with Xcode, I realize it can be a nightmare to share code between projects.  Let's use the following example:  Let's say I'm building several casino apps,  Lets also assume that I've built a "Card" class and a "Card shuffling" class.  These classes can be used for video poker apps, blackjack apps, etc.  I've found that if I've initially built these classes within a blackjack project, I would like to reuse those classes inside a video poker app.   When building the video poker project, I copy and paste my "Card" and "Card shuffling" classes from my blackjack project into my video poker project.

Everything is going well until I need to tweak those classes.  Let's say I'm creating Deuces Wild video poker and I need additional logic in my card class to display "wild 2's graphics" cards.  I do this and then I go back into my blackjack app project.  When I view the "Card" class inside of my blackjack app, the "wild 2's graphics" logic has been written inside that class.  Is there a way to unlink these files so I can edit them without them affecting each other?

Comment: You could make [your own private cocoapod](https://coderwall.com/p/7ucsva)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a file from one project to another, be sure to check the "Copy items into destination group's folder". This will create a new copy of the file specific to the project.

It sounds like you didn't do this and the two projects are sharing a single copy of the file.

To fix what you have, manually copy the file from the original project to the other project. Then in the other project, update the reference to the file so it now points to the new local copy.